# How Spring boot internally handles the http request here?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I see [here](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-microservices-with-spring-boot-part-2-forex-microservice) spring boot packages the microservice artifact as jar file . It handles the http web request through module `spring-boot-starter-web`. 
My understanding is spring boot internally does is

1. Makes the web server up
2. creates the war file , then host the war file on server.
3. Then http requests are handled through servlet lying under spring-boot-starter-web

Is my understnading correct ?

Comment: when the jar is executed, it starts tomcat server internally and upon that your application packaged as war and ran.

Comment: No it isn't... It doesn't package or create a war. It instructs the embedded server where the resources are, it doesn't create an internal war file.

Comment: @M.Deinum Got it, But http request are still handled by servlets like in the given example. Right ?

Comment: It still uses servlets, filters that doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct:

- Starts a embedded tomcat server
- Instructs the tomcat server how to act
- HTTP requests are handled by an underlaying [DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)

Comment: any documentation on this servlet layer? In my company we are using it to handle huge loads of requests (Big Data) and I am trying to understand his effective capacities

Comment: Whoops I didn't put the link correctly, I've updated it. There you can find the documentation

Answer (score 1):

spring boot entry point is main method, inside the main method we are calling SpringApplication.run(<@SpringBootApplication annotated class name> ,arguments);
when we invoking main method,     SpringApplication class internally  start the embedded server, configuratation and deploy the application in server...
    here dispatcher servlet registered in servlet context on OnCondtion checking basis, if we are added spring-boot-starter-web then it checking condtion dispatcher-servlet available or not inside the class path if available then it will in registers the dispatcher-servlet in servlet context